# Paths and names of Deleted files

Tags: windows, metadata, filenames

Accidentally deleted my whole second hard drive with files on it. It was full of games and videos I just don't know which ones. What I want to know is can I find out what files I deleted? Are the file paths or names somehow saved on my ssd with windows? I just want know what folders I deleted.

The Hdd is now formatted and other files were written on it.

Comment: There may be some remnants in the registry depending on how the games were installed. As for the videos some video players (eg VLC) store a list of recently played media.

Comment: There is a chance software such as anti-virus, backup, etc... created a log of all files scanned/backed up.  Maybe use a tool such as Agent Ransack to scan all obvious file types (*.log, *.txt, etc..) that might contain a few distinctive file names that you know were on the disk.  If they match, maybe the log contains more.  If the drive was E: for example, maybe search for `E:\`.

Comment: It is based on how did you deleted it. If you deleted without press shift key and delete key, we might could undo this action. Try to refer to:https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-deleted-files.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you "delete" a file it isn't actually deleted. The pointer to it is deleted, which marks the space the file used to take up as free. There are programs which can recover data after an accidental deletion, which means you may be able to get some of your files back if they haven't been overwritten (it's still possible if they have been overwritten, but it's extremely complicated and I don't think it's possible for the average consumer). Some of the aforementioned programs will work even after formatting the drive. One of them is [EaseUS Data Recovery.](https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm) I formatted a USB flash drive and it was able to find and recover the files.